# Classification of linear systems of partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm working with the linear equations of poroelasticity (describing flow and deformation processes in porous media).  The particular equations i'm working with (in 1D) are of the form

$$-\left(\lambda + 2\mu\right)\frac{d^2u}{dx} + \alpha\frac{dp}{dx} = f$$
$$\frac{d}{dt} \left(c_0p + \alpha \frac{du}{dx}\right) -\frac{1}{\mu_f} \frac{d}{dx}\left(k(x)\frac{dp}{dx}\right)=h$$

I'm familiar with PDE Theory as it applies to elliptic, parabolic, and hyperbolic equations (of a single dependent variable), but I don't know if this theory extends to include systems of linear PDE's as well.  Is there an extension of PDE theory to linear systems of PDE's?  In particular, how do I classify a *system* as opposed to a *single equation*?